# Arrows position in schemdraw flowchart

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, flowchart, schemdraw

I am new to Python, and schemdraw.
I am trying to connect the "**end**" of the flowchart with "**activity 6**".

However the arrow comes out from the side (red arrow, and wrong position), and I'm trying to get it to come out (black arrow, correct position) from the down of the box.

Could someone help me?

```
pip install schemdraw
import schemdraw
import schemdraw.elements as elm

with schemdraw.Drawing() as d:
    d.config(fontsize=14)
    d += (b := flow.Start(w=6, h=2).label('Start'))
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    
    d += (step1 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 1').fill(''))
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    d += (step2 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 2').fill(''))
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    d += (step3 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 3').fill(''))
    
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    d += (step4 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 4').fill(''))
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    d += (step5 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 5').fill(''))
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    d += (step6 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 6').fill(''))
    
   
    # Activities
    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step1.E)
    d += (act1 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 1').fill(''))
    
    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step2.E)
    d += (act2 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 2').fill(''))

    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step3.E)
    d += (act3 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 3').fill(''))
 
    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step4.E)
    d += (act4 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 4').fill(''))
    
    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step5.E)
    d += (act5 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 5').fill(''))

    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step6.E)
    d += (act6 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 6').fill(''))

    # May be here!!!
    d += flow.Arrow().down()
    d += flow.Start(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('End')
 
    d += (phase1 := elm.EncircleBox([step1, step2, step3, act1, act2, act3], padx=.8).linestyle('--').linewidth(2).color('red'))
    d += (phase2 := elm.EncircleBox([step4, step5, act4, act5], padx=.8).linestyle('--').linewidth(2).color('blue'))
    d += (phase3 := elm.EncircleBox([step6, act6], padx=.8).linestyle('--').linewidth(2).color('green'))
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code.

```
 d += flow.Arrow().down().at(act6.S)
 d +=flow.Terminal(w=6, h=2).label('End')
```